# Using Authentication Headers in REST API Proxy, extJS and Chef

Tags: rest, api, authentication, extjs, chef-infra

I am trying to make an API GET request to an endpoint on my Chef Server and was wondering how I could use my username and username.pem file in order to successfully make the request. I am currently using the extJS framework in order to perform this action.

I have an application very similar to this:

[REST Proxy Example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/classic/restful/restful.html)

Where I'd like to display the results of the GET request to a grid.

[Chef Server API GET Cookbooks](https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html#id29)

Using a REST API testing website ([REST API testing](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com)), I have been able to make a simple request with the following code:

```
var listOfCookbooks = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
autoLoad: true,
autoSync: true,
model: 'Optional Cookbooks',
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'
    }
},
listeners: {
    write: function(store, operation) {
        var record = operation.getRecords()[0],
            name = Ext.String.capitalize(operation.action),
            verb;
    }
}
});
```

Previously, I had been using a PHP wrapper to make calls to the Chef Server API which allowed me to set my username and username.pem file:

```
<?php

use Guzzle\Http\Client;
use LeaseWeb\ChefGuzzle\Plugin\ChefAuth\ChefAuthPlugin;

// Supply your client name and location of the private key.
$chefAuthPlugin = new ChefAuthPlugin("my-dashboard", "my-dashboard.pem");

// Create a new guzzle client
$client = new Client('https://manage.opscode.com'); 
$client->addSubscriber($chefAuthPlugin);

// Now you can make calls to the chef server
$response = $client->get('/organizations/my-organization/nodes')->send();

$nodes = $response->json();

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you say extJS I'm assuming you are talking about doing this from a browser. This is not recommended since you would have to load the whole RSA private key into Javascript which is unsafe as you cannot reasonably ensure it won't leak out to other contexts. You'll need some kind of proxy (such as the PHP code you mentioned) which uses a more traditional browser session authentication method like a cookie. Overall this is going to be very difficult and annoying, and I recommend you shrink the scope of what you need.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm thinking. I've been able to set up the PHP code in my project so I will continue using this wrapper. Thanks for the tip

Comment: There is a Chef RFC that was accepted but never implemented to add a token auth mode to the server API which would make this much easier (the proxy would issue a short-lived token and hand it the browser). Maybe some day :)